# ma(c + n + s) =?

Tags: word, knowledge, rebus

This is an original puzzle. It may require some specific knowledge, but nothing that can't be easily acquired.

> ma(c + n + s) = ?

To steer you in the right direction, there are no acronyms involved.

Hint 1:

> Old MacDonald had a farm.
>  And on that farm he had a dog named Clifford,
>  And a cat named Nina,
>  But what was the name of his son?

Hint 2:

> Some subjects from highschool which you may find useful:
> Mathematics initially, to set the stage;
> Language or perhaps even history to understand what you see;
> But physics and chemistry will not aid you here.

Comment: rot13(eryngrq gb purzvfgel?)

Comment: @Adib, I like your thinking, but no.

Comment: (ma)(c)+(ma)(n)+(ma)(s)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I think the answer is

> Christmas

Expanding the equation gives

> mac + man + mas
>  "mac" is a Scottish/Irish surname prefix meaning "son of" so rewriting this gives
>  "son of" + man + mas = "son of man" + mas = Christ + mas = Christmas

Comment: Well done! You cracked it!

Comment: @Earlien What's the relevance of the first hint?

Comment: @ZanyG rot13(Gur qbt naq png jrr erq ureevatf. Gur yvax vf “znp” zrnaf “fba bs”, fb ZnpQbanyq’f fba (jub vapvqragnyyl znl unir orra anzrq B’Qbanyq, “tenaqfba bs” Qbanyq. ) I was going to add a Hint 1b to make this clearer, but it was solved.

Answer (score 5):

> app

Why?

> ma(c+n+s) = mac + man + mas
>  mac is a type of computer
>  man is a type of coder
>  mas is the mac apple store, a place where code is sold
>  add the three together and you get an application, aka app

Comment: Very good guess. Unfortunately that is not the intended answer.

Comment: This is not really a hint, but steer you on the right track, rot13(gurer ner ab npebalzf vaibyirq).

Answer (score 4):

I don't have an answer yet, but here are some of my loose thoughts that might hopefully help someone along the way.

> In physics, the equation `F = ma` stands for `Force = Mass * Acceleration`. If that's what the `ma` refers to, then when you distribute the `ma` to each of `c + n + s`, you get `(Force)c + (Force)n + (Force)s`. Read phonetically, you can get the words Foresee, Forcen(?), and Forces. Foresee and Forces are words, but I could not find a definition for Forcen outside of [this one lone definitiion based on French](https://www.yourdictionary.com/forcen). There is, however, a professional Starcraft player named Forsen whose real name is Sebastian. This could possibly be related to the hint about the son's name but seems specious. It should be noted that the first letter of Clifford and Nina correspond to the `c + n + s` so the answer to the sons name will probably start with an S, but the connection I've made seems unlikely.

Comment: Nice, somebody else also saw the equation connection! But unfortunately I wasn't able to get any further myself...

Comment: Additionally, rot13(Byq ZnpQbanyq'f anzr fgnegf jvgu 'zn').

Comment: Also rot13(Pyvssbeq'f anzr fgnegf jvgu p naq Avan'f anzr fgnegf jvgu a fb fba'f anzr fgnegf jvgu f?)

Comment: @ZanyG Actually you can go one step further: rot13(Pbafvqre gur svefg cneg bs Qe Kbevyr’f thrff. Lbh pna trg “Znp”).

Comment: @Tonkleton Good creative thinking, but not really on the right track. I’ll post another hint soon that should help.

Answer (score 3):

It could be:

> **macanas**, a [weapon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Macana) used by native South Americans. The expression can be rewritten as:
>
>      ma(c + n + s) = m(ac + an + as)
>
>  The symbols then spell out "macanas". (Mathematics, language – the word has entered English from the Caribbean language of Taino via Spanish – and history are used here, but I have no idea what Old MacDonald has to do with mcanas.)

Comment: Good start. Rot13(Gur rdhngvba vfa’g dhvgr va gur evtug sbez lrg. Guvax nobhg ubj ryfr lbh zvtug erjevgr vg).

Answer (score 1):

Is it:

> **dfh**. Using A1Z26, it becomes $13\cdot1(3+14+19)=13\times36=468=\text{dfh}$.

Comment: Sorry, that isn’t it. Rot13(Gur fbyhgvba qbrf abg vaibyir nal ahzoref.)

Answer (score 1):

I didn't find the answer yet but got some useful things maybe lead to the right answer.

> we can sperate the question to "mac + m(an + as)"
> after googling manas, I found some 18th poem called "Epic of Manas" maybe this is the historical part of the riddle. but I couldn't find anything related to mac or Donald about "epic of manas".
> another thing about manas: it could be a state too. it's a state in Kyrgyzstan. but this is not historical.

Answer (score 0):

Partial answer:

(ma)(c)+(ma)(n)+(ma)(s)  Ma being macdonald, and c, clifford, n, nina, s, son

the nina was a ship by christopher columbus

emily elizabeth was clifford's owner

Comment: This is fascinating history which I did not know, but rot13(fnqyl, guvf uvfgbel jvyy abg uryc lbh fbyir guvf chmmyr.  Lbh'yy arrq gb sbphf ba gur rdhngvba n ovg zber.)